# How to fix overlapping markers bug in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerspiderfier

I have a google "my maps" map that contains 5 layers. I've exported each layer out as a .kmz file and imported those layers into a custom.html file using the Google Maps javascript API.

The code is below. The issue I'm trying to address is overlapping markers that share the same lat/long. There can be up to 5 overlapping markers at each location (1 for each layer of my map).

I've seen some references to adding the "spiderfy" library to fix this. However, I can't find any examples that indicate it works with KML layer data.

Can spiderfy work with .kml files? I've tried to implement the code in the "basic demo" on the spiderfy github site but its not spiderfying.

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 11,
    center: {
      lat: 41.876,
      lng: -87.624
    }
  });

  /* FUBO TV */
  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://streambuzz.net/wp-content/uploads/fubo-data.kmz',
    map: map
  });

  /* PLAYSTATION VUE */
  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://streambuzz.net/wp-content/uploads/psvue-data.kmz',
    map: map
  });

  /* HULU */
  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://streambuzz.net/wp-content/uploads/hulu-data.kmz',
    map: map
  });

  /* DIRECTV NOW */
  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://streambuzz.net/wp-content/uploads/dtvnow-data.kmz',
    map: map
  });

  /* YOUTUBE TV */
  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://streambuzz.net/wp-content/uploads/yttv-data.kmz',
    map: map
  });

}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=your_api_key&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: I use this https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack, its for OpenStreetMap and supports clustering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/tree/gh-pages).
 Demo [here](https://jawj.github.io/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/demo-3.html).
It deals with overlapping markers in Google Maps JS API v3, Google Earth-style

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <title>Fancy demo — Overlapping Marker Spiderfier</title>
  <style>
    html, body { height: auto; font: 14px 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif; }
    p { margin: 0.75em 0; }
    ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    a { cursor: pointer; }
    #map_element { position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; }
    #legend { position: absolute; right: 20px; top: 20px; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); color: #fff; }
    #legend ul { padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px; margin: 0 0 0 20px; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map_element"></div>
  <div id="legend">
    <ul>
      <li><b>Move marker</b>: click and drag</li>
      <li><b>Add marker</b>: right-click map</li>
      <li><b>Remove/hide marker</b>: right-click marker</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script>var isIE = false;</script><!--[if IE]><script>isIE = true;</script><![endif]-->
  <script>
    // NOTES
    // this example demonstrates all features:
    // each marker has its own colour, so formatting is done with a marker-level listener
    // markers can be moved (by dragging), added (by right-clicking on the map), and
    // removed or temporarily hidden (by right-clicking on a marker)
    var mapLibsReady = 0;
    function mapLibReadyHandler() {
      if (++ mapLibsReady < 2) return;
      var mapElement = document.getElementById('map_element');
      var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, { center: { lat: 52, lng: -1 }, zoom: 7 });
      
      var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      function iwClose() { iw.close(); }
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', iwClose);
      var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map);
      var white = { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 };
      for (var i = 0, len = window.mapData.length; i < len; i ++) addMarkerWithData(window.mapData[i]);
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function(e) {
        var markerData = { lat: e.latLng.lat(), lng: e.latLng.lng(), rgb: { r: 180, g: 180, b: 180 } };
        addMarkerWithData(markerData);
      });
      function addMarkerWithData(markerData) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: markerData,
          draggable: true,
          optimized: ! isIE  // makes SVG icons work in IE
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', iwClose);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'spider_format', function(status) {
          marker.setIcon({
            url: iconWithColours(markerData.rgb, white,
              status == OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.markerStatus.SPIDERFIABLE ? white : null),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(23, 32)  // makes SVG icons work in IE
          });
        });
        oms.addMarker(marker, function(e) {
          iw.setContent('R: ' + markerData.rgb.r + '<br />G: ' + markerData.rgb.g + '<br />B: ' + markerData.rgb.b);
          iw.open(map, marker);
        });
        function makeLink(text, handler) {
          var a = document.createElement('a');
          a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
          a.addEventListener('click', handler);
          var li = document.createElement('li');
          li.appendChild(a);
          return li;
        }
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', function(e) {
          var ul = document.createElement('ul');
          ul.appendChild(makeLink('Remove', function() {
            oms.removeMarker(marker);
            iwClose();
          }));
          ul.appendChild(makeLink('Hide for 2s', function() {
            marker.setVisible(false);
            setTimeout(function() { marker.setVisible(true); }, 2000);
            iwClose();
          }));
          iw.setContent(ul);
          iw.open(map, marker);
        });
      }
      window.map = map;  // for debugging/exploratory use in console
      window.oms = oms;  // ditto
    }
    var iconWithColours = (function() {
      // generate a data: URI for an SVG marker with specified colors and optional '+' motif
      // I _think_ this will work back to IE9
      function processTemplate(str) {
        var template = str.split('`');
        for (var i = 0, len = template.length; i < len; i += 2) template[i] = encodeURIComponent(template[i]);
        return template;
      }
      function applyTemplate(template, values) {
        var result = template.slice();
        for (var i = 1, len = template.length; i < len; i += 2) result[i] = values[result[i]];
        return result.join('');
      }
      var svgTemplate = processTemplate('<svg viewBox="0 0 23 32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="M22 11c0 1.42-.226 2.585-.677 3.496l-7.465 15.117c-.218.43-.543.77-.974 1.016-.43.246-.892.37-1.384.37-.492 0-.954-.124-1.384-.37-.43-.248-.75-.587-.954-1.017L1.677 14.496C1.227 13.586 1 12.42 1 11c0-2.76 1.025-5.117 3.076-7.07C6.126 1.977 8.602 1 11.5 1c2.898 0 5.373.977 7.424 2.93C20.974 5.883 22 8.24 22 11z" stroke="`stroke`" stroke-width=".6" fill="`fill`" fill-rule="nonzero"/>`plus`</g></svg>');
      var plusTemplate = processTemplate('<path d="M17 11.012c0-.607-.51-1.117-1.115-1.117h-3.222v-3.23c0-.63-.533-1.165-1.163-1.165s-1.163.534-1.163 1.166v3.23H7.115C6.51 9.895 6 10.405 6 11.01c0 .607.51 1.117 1.115 1.117h3.222v3.204c0 .632.533 1.166 1.163 1.166s1.163-.534 1.163-1.166V12.13h3.222c.606 0 1.115-.51 1.115-1.118z" fill="`fill`"/>');
      var rgbTemplate = processTemplate('rgb(`r`,`g`,`b`)');
      return function(fill, stroke, plus) {
        var svg = applyTemplate(svgTemplate, {
          fill: applyTemplate(rgbTemplate, fill),
          stroke: applyTemplate(rgbTemplate, stroke),
          plus: plus ? applyTemplate(plusTemplate, { fill: applyTemplate(rgbTemplate, plus) }) : ''
        });
        return 'data:image/svg+xml,' + svg;
      }
    })();
    // randomize some overlapping map data -- more normally we'd load some JSON data instead
    var baseJitter = 2.5;
    var clusterJitterMax = 0.1;
    var rnd = Math.random;
    var data = [];
    var clusterSizes = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 18, 24];
    for (var i = 0; i < clusterSizes.length; i++) {
      var baseLon = -1 - baseJitter / 2 + rnd() * baseJitter;
      var baseLat = 52 - baseJitter / 2 + rnd() * baseJitter;
      var clusterJitter = clusterJitterMax * rnd();
      for (var j = 0; j < clusterSizes[i]; j ++) data.push({
        lng:  baseLon - clusterJitter + rnd() * clusterJitter,
        lat:  baseLat - clusterJitter + rnd() * clusterJitter,
        rgb: { r: Math.floor(rnd() * 200), g: Math.floor(rnd() * 200), b: Math.floor(rnd() * 200) }
      });
    }
    window.mapData = data;  // for debugging/exploratory use in console
  </script>

  <script async defer src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=mapLibReadyHandler&key=AIzaSyBKx-UGkzpvSol3xk5CiuBK7aSVs_1kgm4"></script>
  <script async defer src="bin/oms.min.js?spiderfier_callback=mapLibReadyHandler"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Overlapping markers]

Of course you need to parse the KML into an array first ([geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/archive/p/geoxml-v3/)).